# How to merge 3 queries into one recordset

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I need to export to excel summary stats from three access SQL queries, as shown below. These are being programmed in vba:

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev2;"
strSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev3;"
strSQL4 = "SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev4;"

'trying to merge the 3 queries above
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL3)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL4)

'to create excel template
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Add()
Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")


With objWS
.cells(1, 1).Value = "X reporting tool"
.cells(2, 1).Value = "District"
.cells(2, 2).Value = Me!subd
 .......
```

Problem in putting all queries in one file access says it's too complex and thus doesn't give output. However when i use the above to merge the SQL queries and have them all export the data into a template created from access vba as above the results are not accurate.

Currently the results are blank in most of the template created, with some values on some parts of the excel template?

hope this makes sense?

Comment: "putting all queries in one file" exactly how did you try that? You've not shown any of the code populating the Excel template, so if data is missing in the Excel file there's no way for us to suggest changes.

Comment: Ok the statement should have said  "putting all queries into one query". This is not happening as the queries are so huge that access SQL says query to complex, that's why I had to separate them. So i'm confident the issue is not with the code for excel as I did two reports and the other report came out fine the query is enough not long to go beyond the required limit required

Comment: "i'm confident the issue is not with the code" - the problem is typically with the code or related to it, so I'm not sure how we could help without it.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a large comment

If all queries return the same amount of columns, you can easily do this:

```
strSQL_union = "SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev2  UNION ALL"
strSQL_union = strSQL_union + " SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev3 UNION ALL"
strSQL_union = strSQL_union + " SELECT * FROM qry_pp_prev4;"
```

You will end with just one resulset.

Comment: Thanks will try this, but the reason for separating them was SQL was complaining about the query being to large as the result is 1 by n matrix were n is more than 255 lines. Each month has about 56 points and multiply that by 12 and you have a 1 by 672 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I know you're asking about how to do this with VBA, but there is a new(ish) solution that is specifically designed to do this without VBA code.

For Excel 2010 and 2013 it's an add-in called "Power Query".  In Excel 2016 it is integrated natively as "Get and Transform" under the data menu.

With this solution you would walk through a wizard to define the 3 connections and describe how merge the data into one table.  You can use DSNs or create the connection via the wizard and more.

**BAM, that's it.**

"Data Refresh All" will connect to the 3 data sources and combine them into one table.

I'm assuming you want to append the data.  It does this just fine.  But, if you are trying to join the tables, this is supported as well.

I've done what you want to do with VBA for years and I'm blown away with what "Power Query"/"Get and Transform" can do.  I can go back and get rid of most of my code.

Here are some resouces to look at:

[Getting Started with Get and Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Getting-Started-with-Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-a8310388-2a12-438c-9d29-c6d29cb8df6a)

[Introduction to Microsoft Power Query for Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605)

Comment: Ok thanks data is being entered in access and we are using access vba to generate an excel template which populates data based on the reports required.... so I will check how to go around this but this could be well be a little bit difficult considering the current solution already built.

Comment: It should work. One of the sources supported by power query is excel workbooks (in addition to database queries, websites, and on and on).